# $7n=x^2+2y^2+4z^2$ with or without $x^2\equiv y^2\equiv z^2\pmod 7$

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

It is well known that any positive odd integer can be written as $x^2+2y^2+4z^2$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$.

**Question 1.** Whether for any odd integer $n>93$ there are $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ such that $7n=x^2+2y^2+4z^2$ but $x^2\equiv y^2\equiv z^2\pmod 7$ fails?

**Question 2.** Whether for any odd integer $n>213$ there are $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ such that $7n=x^2+2y^2+4z^2$ and $x^2\equiv y^2\equiv z^2\pmod 7$?

My computation suggests that both questions might have positive answers, but I don't know how to prove this.

Your helpful comments are welcome!

Comment: Note that $1^2+2\times3^2+4\times2^2=35\equiv0\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y,z):=x^2+2y^2+4z^2$. Then the following automorph of $f$ may help you to solve the problem.

\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z)=f(\frac{x+8y+8z}{7},\frac{-4x+3y-4z}{7},\frac{-2x-2y+5z}{7}).
\end{equation}

Comment: If $y\equiv-3x\pmod7$ and $z\equiv2x\pmod 7$, then $x+y+z\equiv 0\pmod 7$ and so your identity is helpful to Question 2. If $x^2\equiv y^2\equiv z^2\not\equiv0\pmod 7$, then $x+y+z\not\equiv0\pmod 7$ and hence the identity offers no help to Question 1.